# I did the same weight paint, but it changes in rigging

Tags: rigging

[image]

If I hold the neck part and turn it around, rabbit face will turn well.[image]

However, I turn the head part face was crushed.

[image]

head part weight paint[image]

neck part weight paint

Even if the weight paint is the same as the neck part, it still stings.
I just want to watch the class and do the head-rigging.

I want to this that head rigging https://youtu.be/pCcHi-az8Ts

It is my file
[image]

Comment: it looks like head and neck have some vertices in common, maybe you should only control the head with the head bone, considering that this bone is controlled by the neck bone, it should work as expected, no?

Comment: After deleting the weight paint in the neck part, it works properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head and neck vertex groups have some vertices in common, you should only control the head with the head bone, considering that this bone is controlled by the neck bone, it should work as expected.